# Media module, file usage, and simpletest

Tags: media, testing, files

I'm trying to write a test that will do the following:

- Create a user
- Create an 'article' node
- Upload a file via Media module
- Insert that file into the body via pre-determined markup
- Save the node
- Load file usage info to ascertain usage was incremented on node save.

I know all this stuff works right when I test manually.

I know creating a user, letting that user create an article, and saving the node with custom body text works in the automated test.

I'm stuck on how to upload a file via the Media module's media library, the same way it would do if you pressed the 'media browser' button in a WYSIWYG editor that's set up to work with Media.

Ultimately I'd like to be able to test all the features of the latest patch in this issue: https://drupal.org/node/1268116 .

How do I include this type of file upload in my simpletest? I can't use the built-in file upload field because that would mess up testing of Media's handling of file usage tracking.

Comment: can you look in the Media modules /test directory and see how they run their simpletests and that form? Failing that Firebug and drupal_form_submit() with persistance turned on in FB will let you see all the parameters they pass through the Ajaxy file upload window. ... maybe these thoughts will help.

Comment: That is interesting. I didn't know that about Firebug and the Ajax variables.

Comment: See this small tutorial regarding Firebug and submitting forms programmaticaly. http://lionide.wordpress.com/2010/12/06/drupal-7-programatically-create-nodes/

Still, look at the Tests in Media ... because guess what, they do it all in-code :)